# Typescript - ... has no compatible call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i get the no compatible call signatures error and dont know what to do to make it work.

React-State

```
     this.state = {
    categoryState: ...,
    categoryItemId
    }
```

Category declaration

```
let category: Cat1[] | Cat2[] | Cat3[] = this.getCategory();
```

getMethod to return category

```
private getCategory() {
        switch (this.state.categoryState) {
            case "Cat1": {
                return this.props.cat1 as Cat1[];
            }
            case "EVENT": {
                return this.props.cat2 as Cat2[];
            }
            default: {
                return this.props.cat3 as Cat3[];
            }
        }
    }
```

return-Method (react) this is where the error happens:

```
<select value={this.state.categoryItemID} onChange={this.handleSomething}>
                                {(category && category.length > 0) &&
                                category.map((item: any) => {
                                    return (
                                        <option value={item.id}
                                                key={item.id}>{item.localizations[this.props.currentLanguage].title}</option>
                                    );
                                })
                                }
                            </select>
```

error message: 
TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((callbackfn: (value: Cat1, index: number, array: Cat1[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[] |...' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the *exact* text of the error message you get. There may be details in there which will help others answer your question.

Comment: Yes, and also indicate te exact line in which the error happens (not just the line number, but the actual content of the line)

Comment: done:) would you look through it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update 2019-03:  With the release of TypeScript 3.3, there has there has been [progress for calling a union of function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), but unfortunately this pain point [still exists](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#caveats) for generic methods like `Array.prototype.map()`:

---

This is a [pain point](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294) in TypeScript: there's no way to call a "union of function types" unless *either* they accept exactly the same arguments, or [starting in TS3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), if at most one element of the union of functions is generic or overloaded.  In your case, since `category` is `Cat1[] | Cat2[] | Cat3[]`, the method `category.map()` is itself a union of generic functions whose parameters are not the same; and you can't call that.  It should be safe to call `category.map(f)` if `f` is a function which accepts `Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3` (this may seem obvious, but involves understanding [contravariance of method arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_argument_type), which is easy to get mixed up).  But, as the linked issue [mentions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294#issuecomment-190335544), the compiler doesn't let you do that:

> This is currently by design because we don't synthesize an intersectional call signature when getting the members of a union type -- only call signatures which are *identical* appear on the unioned type.

So you get an error.  Luckily there are workarounds.  The easiest in your case is to treat `category` not as `Cat1[] | Cat2[] | Cat3[]`, but as `(Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3)[]`.  As long as you're just reading from the array and not writing to it, it should be safe to do that:

```
let category: Cat1[] | Cat2[] | Cat3[] = this.getCategory();
const mappableCategory = category as (Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3)[];
```

Now you should be able to map over `mappableCategory` instead of `category`:

```
mappableCategory.map((item: any) => { /* ... */ }); // should work now.
```

(Just to reiterate: reading from `mappableCategory` is fine, but writing to `mappableCategory` could be a mistake, since it will happily accept elements of `Cat1`, even if the underlying `category` was an array of `Cat2`.  So don't write to it unless you're sure what you're doing.)

Hope that helps you.  Good luck!