# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature - Array.push()

Tags: typescript, charts

This code below works perfectly fine. It just throws a typescript error. There's no linting or visual error as well. Only on CLI compile time.

```
  const datasets: Chart.ChartDataSets[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    datasets.push({
      label: data[i].Name,
      data: [],
    });
  }

  for (const subset of data.Data) {
      const index = datasets.findIndex(d => d.label === subset.Label);
      datasets[index].data.push(subset.Data);
  }
```

I am using the above code to create a stacked bar chart using Chart.js. I sanitized it and cleaned it up a bit as well.

`subset.Data` is a single number.

`datasets[n].data` is of type: `number[] | Chart.ChartPoint[]`

My exact error is: `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((...items: number[]) => number) | ((...items: ChartPoint[]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.`

I've tried casting `<any>subset.Data` to push and trying `<Chart.ChartPoint>` as well as `<number>` and using the `as` syntax as well. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try casting doing `(datasets[index].data as (number | Chart.ChartPoint)[]).push(subset.Data)`, assuming you are *positive* that `datasets[index].data` is of the same type as `subset.Data`, since the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: Hm, this actually worked for me. Though at first I tried casting to `(number[] | Chart.ChartPoint[])` which didn't work but casting to `(number | Chart.ChartPoint)[]` worked. Also, I think this is related to [Typescript - … has no compatible call signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50929986/1147930)